# Access Image File from path in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having an Web Application(ASP.NET MVC, C#), in which I have a functionality of uploading an excel which contains image path. So I need to know can I access the image files from the application?

PS: Images and Excel will be in the user system.

Comment: so you saying you need to access uploaded xlsx file, extract an image path from that file and do something with these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the users send the real images within the file instead of sending only the paths. This would potentially generate a huge file to upload, but I don't know you application.

Answer (score 1):

If image is at user location then there is no way you can access it (how insecure it would be if any website can access your image file in your system)

So your will need user to upload image as well inorder to use it